# Heroku configuration contains an invalid remoteName

Tags: git, heroku

I just released my project on heroku and not 5 minutes after I get this error everytime I make a change to my file. I have tried everything from reinitiating my project on heroku to deleting my .git folder in my project, I looked everywhere but there seems to be no solution because I wasn't able to find the same issue. Please Help!

I used 
`git push heroku master`
to deploy the project

I have currently github removed as an extension from vscode. This did help solve the problem notification wise, but then again it should be fixed.

[image]

Comment: What git command did you use to try to push? Can you update your answer with that?

Comment: I have added the command that I used to the description.

Answer (score 0):

The command `Command failed with exit code 1: git config --local --get remote.origin.url` fails because you probably don't have a remote called `origin` but rather have it called `heroku`. There seems to be an issue in the extension (see [here](https://github.com/KnisterPeter/vscode-github/issues/856)) and you can circumnavigate it by doing the following:

=> Rename your alias from `heroku` to `origin` by using the following: `git remote rename heroku origin`